# CPU requirements for Gensim modeling

Tags: cpu, gensim, topic-modeling

I am running topic modelling using Gensim on a dataset with 100k rows and 15 columns. The process is taking around an hour to complete and am looking to decrease the time. I was wondering if upgrading my PC would help. Currently I have,

- Processor: Intel Core i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz
- RAM: 8 GB
- Graphics: Intel UHD Graphics 630

Please let me know if upgrading the PC would help or what I can do with current setup to improve the processing time.

Comment: Which Gensim models are you using? Generally, Gensim models work on some corpus (Python re-iterable sequence) where each item is a *text* (list-of-tokens), so describing the size of your data as number of texts, and average count of word-tokens per text, and number of unique words overall, is better for estimating resource needs than 'rows' and 'columns'. (Do you have one text per row, and if so, how many words in the smallest/largest/average text?) Also, performance can be highly influenced by the model parameters you choose.

Comment: So, editing your question to include more info on your actual data size, how it's been prepared for feeding to a Gensim model, which Gensim models you're using, & with what parameters would be helpful in order for answerers to make performance-related suggestions.